# ACF: Update field value based on value of another field

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have some custom posts that lists cars, motorcycles and trucks.

The values in the ACF fileds are automaticaly populated and I cannot change them manually because they come from an external software.

In this CPT I have 2 ACF fields (both are text fields):

one called “Categroy” that can be Cars, Motorcycle, Truck.

Another one called “Service”, that can be a value from 1 to 9.

As you can see the “objects” can have different Categories but they maybe share the same “Service”.

For example:

Categroy = Car Service = 9

Category = Truck Service = 9

I would like to update the value of the ACF Field “Service” based on the value in “Category”.

For example:

if Category is “Car” and the Service is 9, then 9 should be udpated in “Rent”

if Categroy is “Truck” and Service is 9, then 9 should be udpated in “Buy”

How can I achieve that?

Comment: The question needs some formatting and overall improvement, please go read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
and [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) before posting questions.

Comment: I’m sorry, I'm voting to close this question because it's not a code related problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hello You can Use The below Code

```
 function UpdateServiceField($post_id){
    $category_field = get_field('category',$post_id);
    $service_field = get_field('service',$post_id);
    if ($category_field ==9) {
        update_field('service','9',$post_id); 
    }
}
add_action('acf/save_post', 'UpdateServiceField', 20);
```

Comment: Hello. I tried but it did not work :(

Basicall what I need is that if Category is "Car" and Service is "9", the 9 should be rendered like "Rent".

But if Category is "Truck" and Services is "9", the 9 should be rendered like "Buy".

Comment: is this logic in the admin or the front page ?

Comment: and the Category is taxonomy or Field ?

Comment: The logic is better if it's in the admin, "Category" is a Field.